# Swiping upwards in cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to move sprites depending on the swipe direction on the screen. So far, this is the code I came up with based on examples on the internet:

```
-(void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:location];
endTouch = location;

float swipeLength = endTouch.x - beginTouch.x;
float swipeY = endTouch.y - beginTouch.y;    

if(swipeY > 0)
{
 if(swipeLength == 0){
 //Do action here
}}}
```

Now, my question is, I need to limit the endTouch.x range. Like for example it should be greater than 100 but less than 150. I want to do actions only when the swipe is upwards or in a certain angle from between something like 50 to 120 degrees, not by swiping sideways or downwards. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having a little trouble understanding your question. But if you want to get only an upward swipe you should do the following:

1. Get `touchEnd.y - beginTouch.y`.
2. If the result is negative, then it was not an upward swipe.
3. Else continue and figure out the slope `float slope = (touchEnd.y - touchBegin.y)/(touchEnd.x - touchBegin.x)`.
4. Make a threshold, if the slope is not steep enough, it then the swipe is not upward but sideways in terms of direction. `if (abs(slope) >= threshold) { //It's an upward swipe }`

Not sure what you are trying to get at with:

> Like for example it should be greater than 100 but less than 150.

But if you want to limit the angle that constitutes for an upward swipe you can do:

1. Convert degrees to slope (`tan(theta)`) Look at second equation [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope) for why you use `tan(theta)`.
2. So if you want your slope to be within range 90 +- 30 deg: `threshold = tan((pi/180)*30)`

Comment: I found a way around this by removing the x-axis comparison and instead just checking if the difference between beginTouch.y and endTouch.y is greater than 1. If it is, then the sprite would move, if it's not, then nothing happens. Thank you for your suggestion.